# what is the concept behind None?

Tags: python

I am getting None when i typed wrong input but when i typed correct input. It is not appear. kindly help me out with this concepts.

```
def order():
    try:
        count = int(input("How many order ? "))
        return count
    except Exception as e:
        print("Kindly enter in numbers")
        print("Example :- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc..")
    finally:
        print("Thanks to choose our service.")
choice = order()
print(choice, " will be ordered soon!!")
```

Output:

```
How many order ? asdd
Kindly enter in numbers
Example :- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc..
Thanks to choose our service.
None  will be ordered soon!!
```

Answer (score 5):

Functions in Python always return something. If you don't explicitely specify a return value with `return ...`, your function will return, by default, `None`.

If you don't enter a valid input, the `return` statement of your function won't be executed, so `order()` returns `None`, which gets printed as the string `'None'` after that.

You could test the return value:

```
choice = order()
if choice is not None:
    print(choice, " will be ordered soon!!")
```

so that this won't print in case you didn't make a valid choice.

But you probably would like the user to try again until he submits a valid choice:

```
def order():
    while True:
        try:
            count = int(input("How many order ? "))
            return count
        except Exception as e:
            print("Kindly enter in numbers")
            print("Example :- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc..")

choice = order()
print(choice, " will be ordered soon!!")
```

Sample output:

```
How many order ? e
Kindly enter in numbers
Example :- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc..
How many order ? r
Kindly enter in numbers
Example :- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc..
How many order ? 4
4  will be ordered soon!!
```

Answer (score 0):

On exception, call into the same function to retry:

```
def order():
    try:
        count = int(input("How many order ? "))
        return count
    except Exception as e:
        print("Kindly enter in numbers")
        print("Example :- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc..")
        return order()
    finally:
        print("Thanks to choose our service.")
```

Comment: Not the downvoter I guess the reason is `"Thanks to choose our service"` will be printed 100 times if the user inputs correct input at 100th time. `finally` is always executed.

Comment: Yes, true, didn't consider that. I see Thierry provided a much better approach already.

Answer (score 0):

In case of an error (if string is provided as an input for example), your code will go to the `except` block which has no return value (`None` is the default return value) and that's why your `choice` variable will be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

If the input can't be converted into an integer, the exception will be triggered and have no return value since it only display some messages. YOu can return 0 if the value is not a valid number.